# Intent does not resolve

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Keep getting this error while implementing billing. What is going on?

```
01-30 22:33:31.600: E/Finsky(25902): [1] IntentUtils.createIntentForReceiver: Could not find receiver for com.example.game.android
01-30 22:33:31.610: D/Finsky(25902): [1] MarketBillingService.sendResponseCode: Response RESULT_USER_CANCELED cannot be delivered to com.example.game.android. Intent does not resolve.
```

Manifest:

```
        ...
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPalActivity"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
                  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
</application>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

    <service android:name=".api.billing.BillingService" />

<receiver android:name=".api.billing.BillingReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.IN_APP_NOTIFY" />
    <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE" />
    <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Please write your the solution as an answer to your own question,and don't append it to question! You can also accept your answer and let have others have reference.

Comment: Please see below... and above.

Comment: Thats correct way.Now please also accept your answer whenever you are able to,for reference to other who face the same problem!

Comment: Please see,i have edited your question and answer!

Comment: No that's not right. The code that you pulled into the answer was the code that wasn't working. As I said in my answer (that you deleted), the service and receiver need to be INSIDE the appication tag.

Comment: yes..thats right but you should not change the wrong code of your question.you should correct it in your answer.so all i need to tell you was,dont update your question even if its wrong.so that people can relate their problem with your code to see if they have done same mistake as you did or not!!

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Hiral, but I did have the wrong code in the question, and it was unmodified before you changed things around. I have edited back so now the question has the wrong code and the answer has the right code. Hopefully you will agree and make no more edits. Perhaps now that we have everything figured out we can delete all of these comments so as to not confuse other people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service and receiver need to be in the application tag!

```
        ...
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPalActivity"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
                  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
        <service android:name=".api.billing.BillingService" />

        <receiver android:name=".api.billing.BillingReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.IN_APP_NOTIFY" />
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE" />
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but a different solution: I had forgotten to include an <intent-filter> in my <receiver> tag.  It looked like this:

```
    <receiver android:name="com.blah.blah.blah.MessageReceiver">
     <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.IN_APP_NOTIFY" />
     <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE" />
     <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED" />                 
    </receiver>
```

Moral of the story: double check your manifest!